# Array inequalities as Sumproduct arguments

Tags: excel, arguments, formula

Please explain in details what (A1:A10="Ford") and (B1:B10="June") means in the following formula and what value each return:

=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10="Ford")*(B1:B10="June"))

[image]

Comment: It will get the prices of A2,A3,A4 and A5 and multiply the sum of those prices by the sum of the prices from B2, B3, B5, B6, B7, B8 and B10.

Comment: @JeremiahDotNet that's not true

Comment: chancea has given you a comprehensive explanation - if you are using Excel 2007 or later, though, then COUNTIFS would probably be better here (or SUMIFS if you want to sum col C where the conditions are met) - note it looks like your example comes fromm here http://www.xldynamic.com/source/xld.SUMPRODUCT.html - that link also includes a very extensive explanation of SUMPRODUCT

Comment: @barryhoudini yes, i got this example from there, but it was not explained in details there as chancea explains below

Comment: Not sure I agree - there is a detailed explanation if you scroll down far enough (under "SUMPRODUCT explained").......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since column C is actually never being used in this case, the use of `SUMPRODUCT` is actually just the same as using `SUM`.  The `A1:A10="Ford"` and `B1:B10="June"` just return arrays containing true/false values:

```
Make    Month
True    True
True    True
True    False
True    True
False   True
False   True
False   True
False   False
False   true
```

In the actual formula it would look like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT({false,true,true,true,true,false,false,false,false,false}*{true,true,true,false,true,true,true,true,false,true})
```

Since booleans in excel are actually just represented as 1 or 0 they end up like this:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT({0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0}*{0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1})
```

Now when you multiply the arrays think of just like multiplying the matrix:

```
Make    Month
 1    x   1   =  1
 1    x   1   =  1
 1    x   0   =  0
 1    x   1   =  1
 0    x   1   =  0
 0    x   1   =  0
 0    x   1   =  0
 0    x   0   =  0
 0    x   1   =  0
```

So finally it looks like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT({1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0})
```

which returns `3` since there is only one parameter it works just like the `SUM` function.

Now I am assuming you actually want to `SUM` the price of all the `Ford` and `June` combinations so you should use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10="Ford")*(B1:B10="June"),(C1:C10))
```

Which will actually use the `SUMPRODUCT` method to multiply and then sum the products of the two arrays

```
(With SUMPRODUCT)
Make    Month          Price
 1    x   1   =>  1  x  07,500 = 07,500
 1    x   1   =>  1  x  08,300 = 08,300
 1    x   0   =>  0  x  06,873 = 0
 1    x   1   =>  1  x  11,200 = 11,200
 0    x   1   =>  0  x  13,000 = 0
 0    x   1   =>  0  x  14,999 = 0
 0    x   1   =>  0  x  17,500 = 0
 0    x   0   =>  0  x  23,500 = 0
 0    x   1   =>  0  x  18,000 = 0
                         Total = 27,000
```

Hopefully that answers your question

Comment: it is the best answer i have ever seen on this site